# fileprivate extension vs normal extension

Tags: swift, access-modifiers, swift-extensions

I know the difference between `private` and `fileprivate`.

But what is the difference between

`fileprivate extension UIStoryBoard { }`

and

`extension UIStoryBoard { }`

Answer (score 0):

**fileprivate extension**

Defines an entity (class, extension, property, ...) as private to everybody outside the source file it is declared in, but accessible to all entities in that source file.

**extension**

By Defauly all entities(Extensions,..) are internal and available to the entire module that includes the definition (e.g. an app or framework target).